# How to use angular2 html binding in jade? Specifically a([router-link]=["/Default"])?

Tags: pug, angular

So I have an issue as mentioned in the title.

Jade compiles

`li([router-link]=\["/Listen"\]) Listen`

to

`<li [router-link]="/Listen">Listen</li>`

where I need

`<li [router-link]=["/Listen"]>Listen</li>`

I tried escaping with `\` but it won't compile. Should I use some global mixins for this or is there another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://html2jade.org/

try it : li([router-link]='["/Listen"]') Listen